# What values will have the field on Custom Setting when the setting is not set for specified profile

Tags: trigger, community, customsetting, custom

I have a question regarding Custom Settings. I'm implementing a bypass strategy for triggers. I created a Custom setting with one checkbox called Bypass_Processes__c for System Admin. Then in the code, I'm looking for the value in the field.

`public Boolean isDisabled() { Process_Automation_Settings__c bpSetting =  Process_Automation_Settings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId()); return bpSetting.Bypass_Processes__c ? true : triggerDisabled; }`

My question is what value will have the field if there is no setting set for the Profile, for example, Standard user. I have tested and I think it's going to be false, but want to be sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Process_Automation_Settings__c` is a Hierarchy type custom setting, the value of `Bypass_Processes__c` will be the default value defined at the Organization-level if no Profile-level or User-level setting is defined for the current user.

Read the section on "Hierarchy Custom Settings" on the official docs here: [Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm).